# Copying data from one workbook to another, out of range?

Tags: vba, excel

```
Sub FileFromClosedWorkbook()

    'Assign variable name to Target workbook
    Var1 = ActiveWorkbook.Name
    'Assign variable name to Target range
    Var1R = "A1:I50000"

    'Open Source WorkBook
    Application.Workbooks.Open ("S:\private")

    'Assign variable name to Source workbook
    Var2 = ActiveWorkbook.Name
    Var2R = "private"

    'Copy from Source to Target
    Sheets(Var2R).Columns("A:H").EntireColumn.Copy _
    Destination:=Workbooks(Var1).Sheets("Data").Range(Var1R)
    'Close Source WorkBook wo/Save
    Workbooks(Var2).Close False

End Sub

'This button will create the metrics within the workbook
Sub CreateMetrics()
    'Open redeacted data sheet
    'Workbooks.Open Filename:= _
    "S:\private"
    'Sheets("Data").Activate
    'Select and paste all into this workbook

    'Cells.Select
    'Range("A65536").Activate
    'Selection.Copy
    'Sheets("Data").Select
    'Cells(1, 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll

    'Go to very last cell with data in it
    'Store this value
    Dim ending As Range
    Set ending = Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Select
    'Subtract 250, this is because the data has an issue graphing with more values than this
    Dim beginning As Range
    beginning = Range(ending - 250)
    'Choose the sheet
    Sheets("Chart").Activate
    'Create a scatter plot in the next sheet
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart.Select
    ActiveChart.ChartType = xlXYScatter
    ActiveChart.ChartArea.Select
    ActiveSheet.Shapes("Chart 2").IncrementLeft -282.75
    ActiveSheet.Shapes("Chart 2").IncrementTop -184.5
    ActiveSheet.Shapes("Chart 2").ScaleWidth 2.4333333333, msoFalse, _
    msoScaleFromTopLeft
    ActiveSheet.Shapes("Chart 2").ScaleHeight 2.5677085156, msoFalse, _
    msoScaleFromTopLeft
    'Name first series
    'Choose data (last 250 pts) for y-axis
    'Move date into a new column and convert to a number, this is because the date has trouble plotting itself on the x-axis
    'Choose data (last 250 pts) for x-axis
    'Edit axis options, fixed min & max (values as the converted values of the date), major unit of 3
    'Set number as a date and format
    'Rotate the text 90 degrees
    ActiveChart.ChartArea.Select
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Name = "=Sheet2!$G$1"
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).XValues = "=Sheet2!$B$75:$B$318"
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Values = "=Sheet2!$D$75:$D$318"
    ActiveChart.PlotArea.Select
    ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory).Select
    ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory).MinimumScale = 41300
    ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory).MaximumScale = 42000
    ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory).MajorUnit = 100
    ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory).MajorUnit = 3
    ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory).MinimumScale = 41643.2
    ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory).MaximumScale = 41705.04
    Selection.TickLabels.NumberFormat = "m/d/yyyy"
    Selection.TickLabels.NumberFormat = "m/d/yy;@"
    Selection.TickLabels.NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yy;@"
    ActiveChart.PlotArea.Select
    Selection.Height = 449.495
    'Repeat for private and private
    Sheets("private").Activate
    Sheets("private").Activate
End Sub
```

Hello all, I'm trying to copy data from one workbook to another so I can create graphs/metrics from this data and it's giving me a lot of trouble.  This code is just peiced together from online or made with the macro recorder, I'm trying to do it line by line and fix it until it works.  It's giving me an out of range error when I debug it line by line after it opens my file within my S drive (which according to the forum I got it from, was supposed to get the file without opening it). What is causing this?

I'm a complete novice at VBA/programming in general so please excuse my ignorance.  Also, I changed most of the variable names/some of commenting since this is work related.  Excel 2010 if that is relevant.

Thank you!!

Comment: The commented part `Workbooks.Open Filename:= "S:\private"'Sheets("Data").Activate`?  Do you have a sheet named "Data" in your workbook "private".  Also, I think you should provide the extension in the filename.

Comment: Well I intenionally commented that out because the top section was supposed to grab the data without opening it.  I do have a sheet named Data in one of the two workbooks (the workbook I'll be copying it into).  The files are both .xlsxm

Comment: What is the exact line throwing the `Out of range` error?  Do you have a sheet named "private" in source workbook?

Comment: "Subscript out of range", the name of the actual file is different, I just changed it because it's a work file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this (just modified a little your code):

```
Sub FileFromClosedWorkbook()

    Dim Var1 As String, Var1R As String
    'Assign variable name to Target workbook
    Var1 = ActiveWorkbook.Name
    'Assign variable name to Target range
    Var1R = "A1:I50000"

    'Open Source WorkBook
    Application.Workbooks.Open ("S:\Lab Data.xslxm")

    Dim Var2 As String, Var2R As String
    'Assign variable name to Source workbook
    Var2 = ActiveWorkbook.Name
    Var2R = "Chemical"

    'Copy from Source to Target
    Workbooks(Var2).Sheets(Var2R).Columns("A:H").EntireColumn.Copy _
    Destination:=Workbooks(Var1).Sheets("Data").Range(Var1R)
    'Close Source WorkBook wo/Save
    Workbooks(Var2).Close False

End Sub
```

Or this as I found it more robust:

```
Sub FileFromClosedWorkbook()

    Dim Var1 As String, Var1R As String
    'Assign variable name to Target workbook
    Var1 = ActiveWorkbook.Name
    'Assign variable name to Target range
    Var1R = "A1:I50000"

    Dim sourceWB As Workbook
    'Open Source WorkBook
    Set sourceWB = Application.Workbooks.Open("S:\Lab Data.xslxm")

    Dim Var2R As String
    'Assign variable name to Source workbook
    Var2R = "Chemical"

    'Copy from Source to Target
    sourceWB.Sheets(Var2R).Columns("A:H").EntireColumn.Copy _
    Destination:=Workbooks(Var1).Sheets("Data").Range(Var1R)
    'Close Source WorkBook wo/Save
    sourceWB.Close False

End Sub
```

Comment: Bah, I tried the second one and still no luck.  I guess if it makes it a bit more easy to understand, the file within the S drive just call "Lab Data.xslxm" and the Var2R would be "Chemical" (but a sheet, not the file).  

I'm still getting a "Subscript out of range" error.  It's opening up the Lab Data file which I didn't think was supposed to happen?

Comment: Are you sure sheets "Data" and "Chemical" have no spaces before and after their name.  It must be the exact same name.  And for opening a workbook without actually seeing is not possible.  You could maybe use a VBScript or you could try **[.ScreenUpdating Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb221605(v=office.12).aspx)** or the **[GetObject Function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa445016(v=vs.60).aspx)**.

Comment: There are no spaces before or after the name, this is really bizarre.

Comment: I stand corrected, I did have something misnamed.  Thank you so much!!